# Get the equilibrium value in coupled ode by python

Tags: python, ode

I am dealing with a coupled ODE.
I have already plotted the solutions out using `odeint`, but I want to get the value of equilibrium.
The ode looks like this:

```
IN,EnN,c,l,XN,N_init,Bx_init=0.1,0.01,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.4,1
init = (N_init, Bx_init)
def model(init,t, IN, EnN, c, Qn, l, XN):
    N_prime = IN - EnN - c*init[1]*init[0] + XN*l*Qn*init[1]
    Bx_prime = c*init[1]*init[0]/Qn - l*init[1]
    return [N_prime, Bx_prime]
```

where init, t, IN, EnN, c, Qn, l, XN are all constants.
The plot I got looks like this:
[Bx and N](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVni4.png).
I tried using functions like `solve_ivp`, `fsolve`, `root_scalar`, however, I couldn't get the exact time t when Bx or N reaches the equilibrium i.e. get the t when dN/dt=0 and dBx/dt=0.

i followed https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/29961/solving-for-a-set-of-coupled-odes-to-get-correct-variable-values and tied to use `solve_ivp`

```
sol=solve_ivp(model, (0,40),init, method="LSODA", args=(0.1, 0.01, 0.1, 0.025, 0.1, 0.01))
```

However， I got the error

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

Could someone give me a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As it stands, your question is not about a programming problem but about finding an algorithm/technique. This may be suited for [scicomp.se], but even there, you should specify what exactly you want, e.g.: What is your compromise between speed and accuracy? Do you care about the time when the equilibrium is “reached”? And what does *reached* even mean here? You can also ask about how to apply some of the Python functions you mention here, but then please show your attempts so we have at least some understanding where and why you fail and how we can help you.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft thank you for your reply. I want to get the time when Bx and N become steady. I have updated my question. thanks for your advice.

Comment: *I want to get the time when Bx and N become steady.* – But that’s the thing: Strictly speaking they only become steady for t→∞. Numerically, this may happen within a finite time, but it may still not be reasonable to wait for it. Practically, you probably have some accuracy criterion. — Regarding your edit: Why do you expect `solve_ivp` to help you more than `odeint` does? They are just different integration interfaces, partially even for the same integrator.

Comment: odeint uses argument order (y,t), all others and odeint with option tfirst=True uses argument order (t,y). You can compute equilibrium points with fsolve (from scipy.optimize)